# Corrupt H2 Database. Failed to recovery using the Recovery Tool

Tags: java, sql, database, h2

Today one of my H2 database failed to connect and presented the following error message:

```
Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:h2:file:C:\Users\Username\.appfiles\db\appdb) for user 'sa': File corrupted while reading record: null. Possible solution: use the recovery tool [90030-200]

SQL State  : 90030
Error Code : 90030
Message    : File corrupted while reading record: null. Possible solution: use the recovery tool [90030-200]
```

As suggested I tried to use the recover tool as instructed by the documentation, the steps I executed were the following:

1. Go to your h2 data file directory
2. java -cp h2-1.4.200.jar org.h2.tools.Recover
3. Use SQL file generated by the recovery tool to recreate the database

The steps created two files: a .sql and a .txt file, but the SQL generated by the tool didn't have any data or DDL from the database, just some aliases and a bunch of comments. The content of the files are linked below, if they can help shed any light on what went wrong during the process.

This is the .sql file output: https://pastebin.com/DFfwPemP

This is the .txt file output: https://pastebin.com/6zwCgqN3

Is there any step I'm not doing right or is any other thing I can try to recover this db? Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Run that files with

```
java -cp h2-1.4.200.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:[path to destination db file]/[db name] -user [user] -password [password] -script [text file/sql file]
```